# Dynamic JS table using createElement

Tags: javascript, dynamic, html-table

I am pretty new to Javascript so would appreciate your assistance.
I need to generate a table dynamically for weekdays of Monday through Friday.
Then create an element td on the days that match with information I am passing in.
I put together [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r5v7q1js/77/) that I need help with.

I know I am not doing this right. Right now it creates same exact TD for all the days. As you can see here I have set of objects that have different `eventdate`:

```
var dataForPDF = [
    {
        "title":"test1",
        "description":"something here 1",
        "duration":7,
        "eventdate": "4/24/2017"
    },
    {
        "title":"test2",
        "description":"something here 2",
        "duration":4,
        "eventdate": "4/25/2017"
    }
]
```

So what  I am trying to accomplish is to make sure that td with eventdate of 4/24 is only created on Monday, 4/25 on Tuesday, etc.

So at the end of the day I want to see something like this:

[image: table that I want]

Please let me know how to accomplish this.

Comment: You're building the table incorrectly, obviously, but the fiddle contains a bit too much, you should try to narrow it down a bit, noone has an hour to correct your code.

Comment: sorry but it contains exactly what is needed with headers and trs and tds and sample data to go against. Once again, I am new to JS so I don't know how to narrow it down. If you can't help me it's ok. I'll wait for someone who can be of assistance.